# Is it possible to cover line segment [0, 1] with a set of segments having total size less than 1?

Tags: set-theory

It is well known (although its highly counterintuitive) that it is possible to cover all the rational points of segment [0, 1] with a set of segments having arbitrary small total length.

But is it possible to cover ALL the points of segment [0, 1] with a set of segments with total length less than 1?

Comment: How many segments can I use?

Comment: Is this a disguised question that is meaning to ask about the cardinality of the reals?

Comment: @halrankard2 Infinitely many. It is quite easy (I guess) to prove that with finite number of segments it is impossible.

Comment: @AndrewChin I do not know :) I understand that there are "more" real numbers than rational numbers, but do not understand how to use this fact to answer the question.

Comment: Can I use continuum many "segments" which are just singletons $\{x\}$ for all $x\in [0,1]$? If your segments are Lebesgue measurable (which the wording suggests) then you can't do it with countably many.

Comment: @halrankard2 It's a very good question. But probably not. I understand how to define total length of countable set of segments (as a limit), but this definition would not work for continuum amount of elements.

Comment: The question was only posed to clarify the "rules". But, as I say already, you cannot cover $[0,1]$ by countably many Lebesgue measurable sets whose total measure is less than $1$. And this just because of countable additivity of Lebesgue measure.

Comment: Nice question !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function which assigns to an interval $(a,b) \subset \mathbb{R}$ its length $\ell((a,b)) = b-a$ has a property named *countable additivity*. This means that if $A_{1}, A_{2}, \ldots$ are a sequence of pairwise disjoint intervals (which union to an interval), then

$$\ell\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_{n}\right) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \ell(A_{n}).$$

Therefore, if you use countably many intervals which union up to $[0,1]$, then their lengths must add up to 1.

To make sense of the answer below, I think it is necessary to extend the notion of length to *finite unions of intervals*, in the obvious way. The most general notion of a set which accepts a notion of length is called [measurability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_(mathematics)), and I am trying to keep it beyond the scope of this answer.

**Proof:** The hard part is showing

$$\ell\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_{n}\right) \le \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \ell(A_{n}).$$

Let $(A_n)$ be a sequence of disjoint intervals which union to $[0,1]$. By removing at most countably many points (some of the endpoints) we may assume that the $A_n$ are all open intervals $(a_n, b_n)$. We would like to construct an [open cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_space#Open_cover_definition) of $[0,1]$. Note that both $0$ and $1$ are excluded.

Let $\varepsilon > 0$, and let $c_1, c_2, \ldots$ be the excluded points (in any order). Let $B_n$ be the open interval
$$B_n = (c_n-\varepsilon/2^n, c_n+\varepsilon/2^n).$$
Note that $\sum \ell(B_n) = \varepsilon$.

Therefore the set, $\mathcal{C} = \{A_1, B_1, A_2, B_2, \ldots\}$ is an open cover of $[0,1]$, and its union is the interval $(-\varepsilon/2^N, 1+\varepsilon/2^M)$ for some $N, M$. Since $[0,1]$ is compact, we can take a finite subcover, $\tilde{\mathcal{C}}$ (depending on $\varepsilon$), which will consist of some $A$s and some $B$s. Then
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \ell(A_n) + \varepsilon \ge \sum_{A \in \tilde{\mathcal{C}}}\ell(A) + \varepsilon \ge \sum_{A \in \tilde{\mathcal{C}}}\ell(A) + \sum_{B \in \tilde{\mathcal{C}}}\ell(B) > 1.$$
Taking $\varepsilon \to 0$ gives
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty A_n \ge 1$$
as required.

Comment: Sorry, trying to get it. $A_n$ is an interval. What is $inf(A_n)$ ?

Comment: $\inf(A_n)$ is the [infimum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infimum_and_supremum) of $A_{n}$, which is the largest real number not in $A_{n}$. If $A_{n}$ has a minimum, then it equals that number, and for sets with no minimum the infimum is outside. For an interval $[a,b]$ or $(a,b)$ the infimum is simply $a$, and the supremum is $b$.

Comment: I could probably simplify the notation actually, give me a moment.

Comment: Is it always possible to reorder intervals in such a way? Can't it happen that for each $a_n$ there exists $a_m$ such that $m > n$ and $a_m < a_n$?

Comment: Actually, you're right. That reordering is not always possible - for example the intervals could be $[1/2^n, 1/2^{n+1} )$.

Comment: As I understand it is not even possible to cover the segment with disjoint intervals. Because if we have an interval ($a$, $b$) it is now impossible to cover point $b$. So let's talk about "almost-disjoint" segments, such that segments [$a$, $b$], [$b$, $c$] are allowed. If it is be possible to sort these segments - than problem is solved. (I guess given a solution with arbitrary segments I can construct a solution with such almost-disjoint segments). But it's not always possible to sort the segments, so there is no proof.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113655/discussion-between-preferred-anon-and-lesnik).

Comment: That's _if_ $\bigcup A_n$ is an interval; if not there's no such thing as $\ell(\bigcup A_n)$.

Comment: DavidC.Ullrich Absolutely right, thank you.

@lesnik Sorry, my earlier proof was not even vaguely correct, I apologise for misleading you. I believe the updated proof is right, but is more technical than I was originally expecting. I hope it is OK for you.

Comment: Since $[0,1]$ is compact, we can take a finite subcover, $\tilde{\mathcal{C}}$ - !!!, this is the key statement. Thanks a lot!